# How does a H&K guitar amp footswitch work?

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers

I have a 4 channel footswitch for my Hughes & Kettner Attax 300. It worked fine for years, but now it only changes the first 2 or sometimes 3 channels. I wasn't able to find any information on how the channel switching works in this amp on the internet. Is this likely to be a problem with the amp or just a broken footswitch?

It is a simple 1⁄4 two-contact jack. The switch has 4 buttons for the 4 channels. That makes the switching a bit complicatet, because its not just 4 contacts, ergo one per channel. I already tested the cable and the connector, they are not broken.

Comment: More likely to be a broken wire at the footswich end, or at the plug. That's where most abuse of wiring happens.

Comment: stomp switch problem, or internal circuitry issue. check both.